# WebdriverIO waitfor methods don't work as expected

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, wait, webdriver-io

I am working on a set of webdriverIO tests that use a lot of pauses. To make the framework more robust I want to get rid of the pauses and introduce waitfor statements

I have looked through some walkthroughs, and most of them suggest something in the line of this:

```
var decrease = browser.$("//*[@id='somebutton");
decrease.waitForExist(5000)
decrease.click()
```

This doesn't work in 90% of the times however, returning the error message:

An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters ("//*[@id='somebutton'"). (pretty much the same message I get when I remove the wait altogether)

I have tried both waitForExist and waitForVisible without success

I have played around a but, and found out that the following way does work:

```
browser.$("//*[@id='somebutton").waitForVisible(5000);
browser.$("//*[@id='somebutton").click()
```

I am not fond of this solution though, because it requires replication of the locator, which will make support harder in the future.

Can anyone shed some light on why the first option might not be working for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
var selector = "//*[@id='somebutton";
browser.waitForExist(selector, 5000);
browser.click(selector);
```

Also, an example in the api docs shows it being done like this. Notice they left off the `browser.` portion.

```
var notification = $('.notification');
notification.waitForExist(5000);
```

Perhaps that is your issue? Both ways should work though.

One last thing, you don't have to use the xpath for this element if you don't absolutely have to. It's easier to just use the css selector for id.

```
var decrease = $('#somebutton');
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, your first option worked for me. For some reason, the second option didn't work, even when using the css selector for id. It's almost as if declaring the variable doesn't work because the locator is not there yet. But I have my working solution now, so I'm satisfied :)